# Is there a NON-CHEMICAL weapon that can target the central nervous and/or muscular system?

Tags: science-based, technology, warfare, weapons, hard-science

There is research on nerve agents and gases, but are there any man-portable weapons that may be able to harm the CNS without gas? Thanks.

AMENDED: Results in symptoms like shaking, tremors that are not related to any disease process. (I’m a novice.  Thanks.)

Comment: Currently?  Theoretically?  How many shots do you need?  Range?

Comment: If you don't need specificity, a gun or baseball bat will do the trick.

Comment: Could you define a bit more in detail what exactly you mean by "harm" the CNS? Otherwise the technical correct answer would be "a gun" but thats obviously not what you want.

Comment: Perhaps a taser would meet the criteria?

Comment: Do you mean only harm the central nervous system?

Comment: The traditional non-chemical weapon targetting the central nervous system is the beheading axe. And, of course, a bullet to the head will also harm the central nervous system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A massive dose of radiation will destroy the central nervous system and result in the symptoms you describe with death in less than 24 hours.

Comment: Why are you speculating about details from real science, instead of writing your story?

Clearly, a big bullet will do what you ask by ballistics and more usefully even in science, let alone in fiction, why not consider electricity, magnetism, radiation or - since all Worldbuilding is fiction - heresathingium?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of bacteria and viruses that cause paralysis and brain damage; so yes. They can be delivered with injections, coating surfaces and other approaches besides gas. Prions can also cause harm to the nervous system and can be transmitted by ingestion with food- probably other ways too.

They are 'of chemicals' but they are primarly living systems or at least living adjacent for viruses, that can be argued elsewhere I think!

Comment: And prions!  Don't forget those nasty little self-assembling proteins!

Comment: @jdunlop Good idea! Still closer to chemical than virus, but I think proteins are pretty high up on the assembly scale. I've added them to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now that disease processes have been disallowed, another route to look at would be powerful infra-sound or electromagnetic waves. Slightly out there as science goes, but at the same time there are plenty people who report issues with infrasound (for example living near wind turbines) and extreme sensitivty to various frequencies of electromagnetic radiation, mostly associated with wifi an things like 4G and 5G.

Perhaps the most well known in this bracket is Havana Syndrome:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havana_syndrome

Comment: As detailed in the linked Wikipedia article and the March 2023 report on Havana Syndrome, there is no evidence that either electromagnetic radiation _or_ infrasound were related to the symptoms experienced by US nationals.  The current best guess is disparate causes.  Moreover, EMF sensitivity has _never_ been clinically proven.  The plural of anecdote is not data, and as the OP specified `hard-science`, this is not an answer.

Comment: The cause of Havana Syndrome has not been resolved, but that also means that various hypotheticals have not been ruled out. There is a lot "improbable" and "not evidenced" but that doesn't equate to "impossible" and "not science". There is not a proven scientific answer to Havana Syndrome, just hypothesis.  The question only asked for "may be able to harm" not proven to cause harm.

Comment: If the OP had asked for travel methods with the `hard-science` tag and someone put "yogic levitation" because no one has conclusively demonstrated that no one in history has ever levitated using yoga, it still wouldn't be a good answer.  If it were even just `science-based`, then I'd've left it be, but this is not a `hard-science` answer, as the proposed action _has never been demonstrated_.

Comment: It very much has, but in the specific Havana symptoms. All sorts of electromagnetic radition can cause serious health issues, as can infrasound. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_chemistry

Comment: Sure, if you aim a 400W laser at me, it will have serious health effects.  Effects on the CNS (aside from those, as entertained waggishly in comments that you can achieve with, say, an axe or a bullet) are, again, unproven, and in fact counterindicated by studies attempting to replicate the effect.  Moreover, you'll note that the article you linked specifies _ionizing radiation_.

Comment: @jdunlop I had a go at actual yogic levitation once. It is a silly way to travel — really painful as I didn't have a mat, would not recommend, but *technically*… and oh my word, the new age babble on this video is cringe so mute it… *technically* it is a form of locomotion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyXAB5L3EIQ

Answer (score 0):

A well-placed strike with a club can do a number to both the nervous system and the muscles. (And much more besides.) Very much man-portable too. No gas necessary beyond the air for the wielder to breathe.